# Syntax to select previous row in pandas after filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a pd.DataFrame `df` with 5 lines, say:

```
Row    Value
 1      32
 2      25
 3      10
 4      18
 5      21
```

Lets say I use the filter `df[df['Value'] < 15]` and this should return

```
Row    Value
 3      10
```

My question is, I want to access the value for the row before this filter returns True, in this example I want to function to return the value 25 (from Row 2).

My end goal is to apply the condition, get the row above, and test this row for an additional condition.

What pandas functions can I use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shift the mask up by 1.

```
df[(df['Value'] < 15).shift(-1).fillna(False)]

   Row  Value
1    2     25
```

---

More generally, if you're trying to find all rows greater than 15, whose next row is lesser than 15, you can compute two separate masks and AND them:

```
df[(df['Value'].shift(-1) < 15) & (df['Value'] > 15)]

   Row  Value
1    2     25
```

Comment: thanks! what if i want to take this one step further and check if this value is above 15?

Comment: @AdrianY `df[(df['Value'] > 15).shift(-1).fillna(False)]`?

Comment: sorry i should be clearer. i meant check if the value in row 2 is above 15. does df[(df['Value'] > 15).shift(-1).fillna(False)]['Value'] >15 work?

Answer (score 4):

### `np.flatnonzero`

To find where the mask is `True` then subtract one

```
df.iloc[np.flatnonzero(df.Value < 15) - 1]

   Row  Value
1    2     25
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `idxmax`

```
>>> df.iloc[df.Value.le(15).idxmax() - 1]

Row       2
Value    25
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `nonzero`

```
df.iloc[(df['Value'] < 15).nonzero()[0]-1]
Out[34]: 
   Row  Value
1    2     25
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `.nonzero`

Comment: I have just the bag to put it in.

Comment: @piRSquared my bag is not big enough to put all the beauty you had show to me :-)

Comment: You are too kind.  You have learned many tricks and showed me a few as well (-: