# with pandas boolean indexing, can I access the previous element?

Tags: python, pandas

(Panda beginner here)

Let's assume 2 series: a and b

and the following code:

```
c = a[b > 0]
```

how can I access the previous value of b in order to get something like

```
c = a[b_from_previous_index > 0]
```

and, additionally, how can the index 0 case be handled by pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax to select previous row in pandas after filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034054/syntax-to-select-previous-row-in-pandas-after-filtering)

Answer (score 0):

```
c = a[1:]
```

will give you the second value/position or '1' and all values following

```
c = a[0]
```

will give you the first value/first position in a series or list

```
c = a[:x]
```

will give you all values up to that position in your list/series' index

```
c = a[x:x]
```

will give you values within a range based on the index of your list/series

Does that answer your question? If not give me more clarification or an example of the output your looking for and I should be able to help

Comment: I like Scott's answer, sounds more like what your looking for

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a somewhat hidden duplicate of [Syntax to select previous row in pandas after filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034054/syntax-to-select-previous-row-in-pandas-after-filtering), however for posterity:

```
a = pd.Series([-3,4,-1,-5,2,9,1])
print(a)

0   -3
1    4
2   -1
3   -5
4    2
5    9
6    1
dtype: int64

b = pd.Series(np.arange(7))
print(b)

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
dtype: int64

b[(a<0).shift(-1).fillna(False)]

1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```

You can use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) backwards to get the indices of Series one before the matches. The 0 index is dealt with the `fillna` method, which you can change by making it `.fillna(True)`.

**Note:** You can't leave this blank as pandas Boolean arrays cannot contain NaNs (which are what are used to fill in these spaces by default).